# Function restart works incorect

Tags: javascript

I have just started learning JS and i wrote a code for rock-paper-scissors game. So I have a trouble with next steps: if at first time user's choice and computer's choice are the same - function starts again. But at the second time doesn't matter what user's choice will be because program uses value input from the first time and ignoring the second. Please, explain where is my mistake. The code is below.

```
function compare(choice1,choice2) {
  choice1=prompt("Make your choice!");
  console.log("You're choosing "+choice1);

  choice2=Math.random();
  console.log("Computer rolls the dice and the result is "+choice2);

  if (choice2 < 0.333) {
    choice2="rock";
  } else if (choice2 < 0.666) {
    choice2="paper";
  } else {
    choice2="scissors";
  }

  console.log("That means "+choice2+".");
  if (choice1===choice2) {
    console.log("Ooops!Tie!");
    compare();
  }
  if(choice1==="rock") {
    if(choice2==="scissors"){
        return("Your rock wins");
    } else {
        return("Computer's paper wins");
    }  
  } else if (choice1==="paper") {
    if(choice2==="rock") {
        return("Your paper wins");
    } else {
        return("Computer's scissors wins");
    }
  } else if (choice1==="scissors") {
    if(choice2==="rock") {
        return("Computer's rock wins");
    } else {
        return("Your scissors wins");
    }
  } else {
    return("Nice try smirky!");
  }
}
compare();
```

Comment: post your code in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: probably instead of just calling `compare();` in your "tie" method, you should break the current method. Either `return compare();` or `compare(); return;`

Comment: It's unclear to me why the `compare` function takes arguments.

Comment: @DavidWeldon because he doesn't know you can declare local vars with var inside the function scope?

Comment: [Anyone for some code golf?](http://jsfiddle.net/NspRY/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**My comment on global vars doesn't really hold since I missed that you declare them as parameters, which does creates them in a local scope. It doesn't actually create a global, but you should still remove the parameters and use `var`.**

I do get a proper response every time, no matter how many times I call `compare` or get a tie.

What you do want to change is your variable assignments:

`choice1=prompt("Make your choice!");` makes a global variable of `choice1`, while

`var choice1=prompt("Make your choice!");` creates a local variable in the 'scope' of the function, i.e. isolated every time you run it.

You need to add `var` the time you initialise the variable (the first time you assign it). This doesn't seem to cause your bug, but is a good practise anyway.

Also, your `compare()` call in case of a tie doesn't return its result. You should make sure that also returns:

```
if (choice1===choice2) {
    console.log("Ooops!Tie!");
    return compare();
}
```

This also prevents you from returning "Nice try smirky!" in case of a tie, because that's the first `return` statement it encounters.

Comment: Incorrect, his function has arguments, his vars won't be global

Comment: Whoops missed the parameters to the function, not really globals.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to structure your code is like this:

```
var choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
function startGame(){
    var choiceHuman = prompt('Make your choice!');
    var choiceComp = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
    console.log(determineResult(choiceHuman, choiceComp));
}
function determineResult(choiceHuman, choiceComp){
    if (choiceHuman === choiceComp){
        return 'Ooops!Tie!';
    } else if (choiceHuman === 'rock') {
        if (choiceComp === "scissors") {
            return("Your rock wins");
        } else {
            return("Computer's paper wins");
        }
    } else if (choiceHuman === "paper") {
        if (choiceComp === "rock") {
            return("Your paper wins");
        } else {
            return("Computer's scissors wins");
        }
    } else if (choiceHuman === "scissors") {
        if (choiceComp === "rock") {
            return("Computer's rock wins");
        } else {
            return("Your scissors wins");
        }
    } else {
        return("Nice try smirky!");
    }
}
var userInput = true;
while(userInput) {
    startGame();
    userInput = prompt('Play again? (Y/N)') === 'y';
}
```

The recursive call to compare() has no purpose and it prevents memory from being disposed of. Granted, for this example you probably won't ever get in trouble for it, but for more complex cases, it can end up hurting your performance.